# Every combination of integers between specific range in combination with a list of strings

Tags: c#, list, algorithm

I have the following problem:

I have three elements a, b and c. And also integers from 0 to 100. How can I get all the possible combinations to look like:

```
a 0 b 0 c 0
a 1 b 0 c 0
a 0 b 1 c 0
a 0 b 0 c 1
a 1 b 1 c 0
...
a 100 b 100 c 100
```

and so on? I am using C# but I am rather struggling to find the correct algorithm independently of programming language. Unfortunately I do not really understand carthesian products etc.

Comment: Did you try to search for documentation and existing answers?

Comment: it seems like you want to *loop* over all elements *for* both these lists

Comment: a, b and c are always at same position, so to generate all results, you basically just need all combinations of three numbers out of given integers: `000` (represent a0b0c0 result), `001`, `002`, ...`333`.

Comment: `var list = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; foreach (a in list) foreach (b in list) foreach (c in list) { ... }`

Comment: @Sinatr But I need it to work also for higher numbers than 9

Comment: Can you use a loop to write out all integers of 0 to 100 (for the "a" numbers)? Can you add a second loop (for the "b" numbers) inside this? Can you extend this for "c"?

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Show us some code and where you got stuck.

Comment: I'd be glad if you could write more 5 lines of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to

> find the correct algorithm independently of programming language

So I shall try to answer this using the minimum of programming language features. The example I shall give assumes the programming language has expandable lists, arrays, arrays of arrays and the ability to shallow clone an array. These are common programming features, so hopefully this will be OK.

To solve this problem, you need to produce all the combinations of 3 sets of N integers where each set consists the integers from 0..N-1. (The set of combinations of a set of sets - which is what this is - is called the Cartesian Product of those sets.)

The solution below uses recursion, but we don't need to worry about stack overflow because the stack depth does not exceed the number of sets to combine - in this case, 3. (Normally with recursion you would try to use a stack class to manage it, but that makes the code more complicated.)

### How it works:

`combine()` recursively iterates through all elements of each set, and at each level of recursion it begins processing the elements of the next set.

So the outer level of recursion begins iterating over all the elements of set[0], and for each element it fills in the next item of the current combination with that element.

Then: if that was the last set, the combination is complete and it is output. Otherwise: a recursive call is made to start filling in the elements from the next set.

Once we have all the combinations, we can just iterate through them and intersperse them
with `a`, `b` and `c` as per your requirement.

Putting this together:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var sets = createSets(3, 10);
            var combinations = Combinations(sets);

            foreach (var combination in combinations)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"a {combination[0]} b {combination[1]} c {combination[2]}");
            }
        }

        static int[][] createSets(int numSets, int intsPerSet)
        {
            int[][] sets = new int[numSets][];

            // All the sets are the same, so we can just use copies of it rather than create multiples.
            int[] oneSet = new int[intsPerSet]; 

            for (int i = 0; i < intsPerSet; ++i)
                oneSet[i] = i;

            for (int i = 0; i < numSets; ++i)
                sets[i] = oneSet;

            return sets;
        }

        public static List<int[]> Combinations(int[][] sets)
        {
            var result = new List<int[]>();
            combine(sets, 0, new int[sets.Length], result);
            return result;
        }

        static void combine(int[][] sets, int set, int[] combination, List<int[]> output)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sets[set].Length; ++i)
            {
                combination[set] = sets[set][i];

                if (set < (sets.Length - 1))
                    combine(sets, set + 1, combination, output);
                else
                    output.Add((int[])combination.Clone());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Notes

1. This is an inefficient implementation because it returns all the combinations in one huge list. I kept it this way for simplicity (and to reduce the number of program language features required for its implementation). A better solution in C# would be to pass in an `Action<int[]>` to be called with each combination - then the results wouldn't need to be returned via a huge list.
2. This doesn't produce the results in the same order as your sample output. I have assumed that this doesn't matter!
3. A great Linq implementation of the Cartesian Product is [presented by Eric Lippert here](https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/). I highly recommending reading it!

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the output doesn't matter, this should be enough:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <= 100; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k <= 100; k++){
            Console.WriteLine($"a {i} b {j} c {k} ");
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a 0 b 0 c 0 
a 0 b 0 c 1 
a 0 b 0 c 2 
a 0 b 0 c 3 
...
a 100 b 100 c 100
```